# Can't use add_roles in my for loop discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a command that when invoked will take a list of user ids from a mongodb collection, a list of role names from a different mongodb collection and then works through these lists to see which roles need to be assigned to which ids.

I can get it to print out the correct ids that need the role but I just cannot get past the last step of actually assigning the role.

```
    @commands.command(
        name='assignRolesByExp',
        aliases =['arbe'],
        description="Assign all members roles based on their Exp Points",
        #usage='[Role Name]',
    )
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def assignRolesByExp(self, ctx):
        people = await self.bot.expAcc.get_all()


        roles = await self.bot.stockroles.get_all()
        filtered_roles=[]
        for i in roles:
            if i["expRequired"]>0:
                filtered_roles.append(i)

        for i in filtered_roles:
            roll_to_add = []
            role_name = i["_id"]
            role_exp_required = i["expRequired"]
            #print(role_name)
            for i in people:
                if i["expValue"]>= role_exp_required:
                    roll_to_add.append(i["_id"])
            
            for i in roll_to_add:
                user= ctx.guild.get_member(i)
                await user.add_roles(role_name)
```

The error I get is:
File "D:\WORK\DISCORD BOT\Tranquility\cogs\roles.py", line 339, in assignRolesByExp
await user.add_roles(role_name)
File "C:\Users\johnj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 676, in add_roles
await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're passing a `str` rather than a `Role` to `add_roles` as defined in the discord.py [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles). Impossible however to say how to go about fixing that without access to the rest of the source code, just make sure that you are retrieving the `Role`s as actual `Role` objects rather than just their string names.